# Unable to start Jakarta EE based JSF web application on JBoss EAP 7.4.6

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are running fine a JSF based UI on JBoss EAP 7.3 and now migrating it to Jboss 7.4.6. We updated the standalone.xml as per the Jboss 7.4.6 instructions, but are getting the error like below:-

```
13:19:47,946 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "web-2.20.1-jboss7.war")]) - failure description: {
   ** "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "org.wildfly.remoting.outbound-connection.remote-ejb-connection",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".beanmanager"
    ],**
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cweb-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"cweb-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".WeldStartService]",
        "jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.deployment.\"web-2.20.1-jboss7.war\".internal-remoting-profile is missing [org.wildfly.remoting.outbound-connection.remote-ejb-connection]"
    ]
13:19:48,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "web-2.20.1-jboss7.war" (runtime-name : "web-2.20.1-jboss7.war")
13:19:48,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".batch.artifact.factory, service jboss.deployment.unit."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
      service org.wildfly.remoting.outbound-connection.remote-ejb-connection (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.deployment."web-2.20.1-jboss7.war".internal-remoting-profile] 
WFLYCTL0448: 5 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

Even as per the error we have `<outbound-socket-binding>` configured in standalone as below but still we getting the same error.

```xml
<outbound-socket-binding name="remote-ejb">
    <remote-destination host="localhost" port="8380"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Comment: Is there an error further up? It looks like there is a CDI issue.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins nothing as such relevant error, at last server starts with this error --> 
started (with errors) in 135456ms - Started 381 of 576 services (9 services failed or missing dependencies, 341 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)